# Only copy cell value if active cell is in table column

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a macro that checks whether or not the user has selected a cell within a certain column, then copies that cell's value to another sheet. I keep getting a type mismatch error in the very first line where I'm checking to see if the user has selected a cell in the second column. Here's my code:

```
    If Intersect(ActiveCell, ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns(2)) Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "You must select a cell in the appropriate column.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Error"
Else
    ActiveCell.Copy
    Sheets("Destination").Range("G3").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End If
```

I'm guessing it has to do with my use of ListColumns...?

(I don't want the header row to count as a valid selection, so really only the body of column 2.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. I just needed to add DataBodyRange to that line. Code is now:

```
If Intersect(ActiveCell, ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "You must select a cell in the appropriate column.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Error"
    Else
        ActiveCell.Copy
        Sheets("Destination").Range("G3").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End If
```